# Can you host Magento on Heroku?

Tags: mysql, magento, heroku

I have Magento running on Heroku but the DB is on Dreamhost (because Heroku doesn't host mySQL).  I get a Database connection error from Magento whenever I try to connect.  Anyone ever done this?

Comment: Did you configure the database to allow external connections? By default they're only accessible from within the Dreamhost system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, I just wrote a blog post on doing just this
http://markshust.com/2012/10/29/deploying-magento-heroku-amazon-rds

Answer (score 1):

See http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mysql#Connect_to_Your_MySQL_Database_from_Third-Party_Programs instructions for making your mysql instance visible to your heroku app.